# ERPNext n8n integration document list not loading

Tags: erpnext, n8n

I using ERPNext version 14 and trying to integrate it with n8n when I add the credential for ErpNext in n8n it shows connection success. But when I add the workflow there is field to list down the Doc types in ERPNext but showing empty I couldn't figure out issue. Can some one help me on this?

What I tried is choose the credentials of ERPNext which I saved earlier and it of administrator user therefor no issue with permissions. chose document in resource field, Get Many in operation field but DocType Name or ID field is empty therefor I cannot choose it, I have tried refresh button also.